# PHPExcel setRowHeigt -1

Tags: height, row, phpexcel

I use phpoffice/phpexcel and I have problem with autofit row height.

I've found I should use:

```
$height = -1;
$sheet->getStyle("B$rowNum")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getRowDimension($rowNum)->setRowHeight($height);
```

It doens't work for me. But if I set **$height = 40;** it works correctly.

I've found in **PHPExcel_Worksheet_RowDimension** class method **setRowHeight**:

```
class PHPExcel_Worksheet_RowDimension
{
    [...]

    private $_rowHeight = -1;

    [...]

    public function setRowHeight($pValue = -1) {
        $this->_rowHeight = $pValue;
        return $this;
    }

    [...]
}
```

So - actually **-1** is default value for row height and defaultly row height isn't fitted.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` is the default height: but there isn't an autosize for row height in there is for column widths. It's not a function that MS Excel provides, so it isn't done in PHPExcel either. You can only set a row height to a specific dimension, or tell it to apply the default.